# csv indexerror: list index out of range

Tags: python, csv, index-error

I have a csv file ('data_counter_1.csv') which looks like below:

```
N;52201261;EM3000v2;2.0;20210801000000;20210801010000;20210801010000;51.28983;15.22345;172.19.224.70;0.0.0.0;ns;

C;20210801000500;127;51.28984;15.22344;127;0;0000000000000;3880356.4*kWh;978928.9*kWh;127;0.6*kWh;0.0*kWh;127;

C;20210801001000;127;51.28984;15.22345;127;0;0000000000000;3880357.0*kWh;978928.9*kWh;127;0.6*kWh;0.0*kWh;127;

C;20210801001500;127;51.28984;15.22344;127;0;0000000000000;3880357.6*kWh;978928.9*kWh;127;0.6*kWh;0.0*kWh;127;

C;20210801002000;127;51.28984;15.22344;127;0;0000000000000;3880358.2*kWh;978928.9*kWh;127;0.6*kWh;0.0*kWh;127;
```

I want specific values from csv file export to excel; one value from (let's say) N-row will be the first value for rows created with specific C-rows values.
I wrote a code in pyhton (below), which I thought one should have dealt with this simple task. Unfortunately, while running script I get error: "if row[0] == 'N': IndexError: list index out of range" or "if row[0] == 'C': IndexError: list index out of range" if I modify the code a little.

I've tried to deal with this for a couple of days so I would be grateful for help or at least a tip. Much thanks in advance for Your time.

My code:

```
import csv
from openpyxl import Workbook

workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

with open('data_counter_1.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == 'N':
            const_value = row[1]
        elif row[0] == 'C':
            row_data = [const_value, row[1], row[8], row[9], row[3], row[4]]
            worksheet.append(row_data)

workbook.save('output_counter_1.xlsx')
```

I would be grateful for help or at least a tip. Much thanks in advance for Your time.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the `row` variable? Just between the `for` statement and the `if-elif` statement.

Comment: Is the file empty? If the error is because `row[0] is out of index` that would mean `row` is an empty list.

Comment: Note that your example input file has empty lines every other line. If that is an accurate example file, than that's the problem: empty lines.

Comment: After printing out row variable I got two results: 1. 'N-row' as a list. 2. Empty list []

Comment: If the problem is with empty lines then why I get error even with N-row. I guess script should execute N-row as it has values in it and then give error for C-row. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PrzemekD You get an error because you're trying to look at an index in `row` that doesn't exist. Add a conditional that ensures `row` isn't empty prior checking the N-, and C-row.

Comment: Big thanks to everyone :) I've modified my code a little according to your tips and it works perfectly.

In fact one more line did all the work :)

filtered_rows = filter(lambda row: any(field.strip() for field in row), reader)

Comment: If you like, you can self-answer your question, for completeness; and perhaps it helps someone in the future. (My own solution would have been to put a `if row:` above the if-elif section, but it's context dependent what works (better).)